# get token string for ace editor

Tags: token, ace-editor

I just looked at the kitchen sink demo and see that there is an option "Show token info" that shows up what type of text the mouse is over (variable, function etc.)

I want to create something similar that can get the current token string of the word at the current cursor position. Does anyone knows how to do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this way:

```
editor.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var position = e.getCursorPosition();
    var token = editor.session.getTokenAt(position.row, position.column);

});
```

It will return an Object:

```
token = {
  type: "paren.rparen",
  value: "}",
  index: 0,
  start: 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! Looks though as if the function to retrieve the position has changed: `e.getCursorPosition()`.

Comment: FYI You could also get the token on cursor change if you don't want to use the mousemove event.

Comment: Note that the **mouse** position is different from the **cursor** position. You should probably use `editor.onCursorChange` rather than the `mousemove` event. (Unless you want to detect which token the mouse pointer is at, in which case I'm stumped!)

Comment: You now should use the e.getDocumentPosition() to get row and column values.